# Procedure for finding the right MOSFET, diode and resistor to make a solenoid valve open/close?

Tags: mosfet, solenoid, flyback

I need a right MOSFET to make a 8 valves open/close about 15 times per second! It needs to switch very fast. Anything that can slows the speed of the valves is not desirable.

From what I see the valve is operating at approximately 12VDC, 0.55A.

I want to be able to control these valves with Arduino Uno or Mega and even possibly with Duo in the future. (with 5v output signal)

The valves are [Airtec 2P025-08](http://en2.airtac.com/upload/201405060401124066.PDF)

I did my best to choose the right MOSFET. I don't care about the price and I'd rather to choose extra bucks to be on the safe side and make the circuit last longer.

So far I have chosen this MOSFET:  [Fairchild Semiconductor FQP50N06L](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FQ/FQP50N06L.pdf) It is a power MOSFET but to me it is nothing wrong with it to make me go for logic MOSFET.

My questions:

1. Why should one choose a logic MOSFET for such an application? The gate voltage seems fine with me. And some of the websites list this model as logic/power MOSFET!
2. What is the exact procedure for choosing the right MOSFET?
3. Is my Arduino capable of providing enough current to control 8 of these MOSFET to make the valves open/close? I mean is it able to provide enough ampere at digital outs? vales has an external 12v battery themselves.
4. I don't know how to choose the right flyback diode? Does it have to be able to handle several times of the normal voltage and current passing through the circuit? Is IN5401 (100v, 3 A) enough? or Should I choose one with higher Ampere rating?
5. What resistor should I choose for the digital to ground pin of Arduino? I have seen 10K for such applications but I don't know how they choose this number for it!
6. Is Schottky diode more proper for this application!? If yes how can I choose the right one?
7. And the most important question. Is making the diode series with a resistor going to affect the speed of the circuit? I read somewhere that it can affect it in negative way when opening and closing at very fast speed is important. Or am I wrong?. But wasn't able to find any explanations. Speed is crucial for me. If a resistor can help me, What should be the value of the resistor for my application?
8. And do you think that the chosen MOSFET is going to do the job for me?

Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Why not split up your question in two logical parts: MOSFET (1, 2, 3, 8) and flyback diode (4, 5, 6, 7)? I didn't check, but I bet there are similar questions on EE.SE already (see the top right column "RELATED").

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your project which I won't address because there's one fatal flaw which is going to shut you down, and that's the operating speed of the solenoid, which is specified as 50 milliseconds.

The data sheet's a little sketchy, but if it takes 50ms to open the valve and another 50ms to close it, that's 100ms, which means that it'll take one second just to open and close a valve 10 times, not the 15 times per second you're looking for, and that's not even taking account of how long you want the valve to stay open and let whatever your medium is, flow.

To worsen the picture, any flyback diode you use will slow down the solenoid's return to its normally closed position, so at this point your chance of success looks slim. Sorry. :-(

Comment: Thanks, I know about that. Honestly I highly doubt that it even reach to 10 times per second. They are going to stay in on or off state for 1 or 2 seconds . But at the beginning of the experiment, they are going to switch around 5 to 8 times. For me 15 was a perfect figure! by the way I count each on and off separately!! so by 15 I means 8 on and 7 off! So I'd be so happy if you could tell me what's wrong with this approach! thanks.

Comment: Is adding a resistor in series with flyback diode going to help !?

Comment: @arudino.tyro: 1.`I'd be so happy if you could tell me what's wrong with this approach.` I don't understand your reasoning, but if you'd go back and edit your post to include timing diagrams for both stages of the experiment that would help to clear it up.

Comment: @arudino.tyro: 2.The resistor will help, but the best way to do it is to place a Zener in series opposition with the flyback diode: flyback cathode to the positive rail and Zener cathode to the MOSFET's drain. Choose a MOSFET with as high a Vds as you can afford, and a Zener a little bit lower than that so that the string will break over at Vz plus the flyback's Vf  before Ldi/dt kills your MOSFET.

Comment: you mean like this? http://i.stack.imgur.com/5qE5j.png

Comment: @arudino.tyro: Yes; third from the left.

Comment: One quick question? Is it possible to use "avalanche rated MOSFET for this application?! I think they have a built in Zener diode !?